# Using custombox plugin in asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can I use **[custombox](http://dixso.github.io/custombox/)** plugin to render actions in asp.net mvc?

With modal **boostrap**, I use the following code, but the same code gives error with **custombox**:

**BUTTON**

```
<a class="btnModal btn btn-primary" href="javascript:;" data-href="@Url.Action("Create")">New</a>
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".btnModal").click(function () {
    $("#myModal").load($(this).attr("data-href"));
    $("#myModal").modal({
        backdrop: 'static',
        keyboard: false
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the same code to open both a bootstrap modal popup and a custombox.They are two different plugins.To launch a custombox popup you can use the code below:

```
<script src="~/scripts/custombox.js"></script>
<link href="~/css/custombox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".btnModal").click(function () {
            $("#modalBody").load($(this).attr("data-href"));
            Custombox.open({
                target: '#myModal',
                zIndex: 'auto'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<a class="btnModal btn btn-primary" href="javascript:;" data-href="@Url.Action("Create")">New</a>
<div id="myModal" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#fff;">
    <div id="modalBody">
    </div>
</div>
```